# After updating firebase last version, MultiDexApplication error started

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

Hi I am codding with Kotlin. Everything was perfect. After adding

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.1'
```

lines in build.gradle It started that getting

```
 Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file.................
```

error.

What is the problem. I am giving some build.gradle files codes.Maybe it is necessary to say somethig. Thanks

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 30
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
   
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mygdx.game"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
  




 dependencies



    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.1'
   // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'




eclipse.project.name = appName + "-android"
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating multidex version..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).